# How to identify the mapped/owned sides of a self-referencing one-to-one relationship in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, one-to-one, relationships

My Hibernate schema has a Port entity. Each Port should have zero or one connections to another Port so there is a "connectedPort" field referencing the same entity:

```
public class Port {
    // ...
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private Port connectedPort;
    // ...
}
```

But normally for a @OneToOne there would be an "owned" side of the relationship and a "mapped" side of the relationship - is this also the case here - and if so, how and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `OneToOne` API doc:

> If the relationship is bidirectional, the non-owning side must use the `mappedBy` element of the `OneToOne` annotation to specify the relationship field or property of the owning side.

So, either your `connectedPort` has no relationship to its reverse connected port and the holder of the field `connectedPort` has the foreign key, or the relationship is bi-directional and you have to specify who holds the foreign key using `mappedBy`.

**Edit** As I assume from your code snippet your connected ports have no knowledge of who is connected to them, so your `Port` holding the knowledge to whom they are connected hold the foreign key and are the owning side of this relationship.