# Spring Boot/Hibernate: How to define one-to-one unidirectional relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, curl, spring-boot

I have `People` entity that has `name` and `parent` where `parent` is a `People`.

```
@Entity
public class People {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column
    @NotNull(message = "error.name.type.null")
    private String name;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private People parent;

    // getters and setters
}
```

When I store data using `PUT`, I specify the id `1` as a path variable and provide the `name` as data input and did not pass `parent` like:

`curl -i -X PUT -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"name":"John"}'`

Response

```
http://localhost:8080/people/1
HTTP/1.1 200 
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 12 Oct 2016 13:51:52 GMT
```

When I retrieve what is stored, `parent` already have a link to the object itself although I passed `null` when making the `curl` request.

What am I doing wrong with the Hibernate `One-to-One` relationship?

```
curl -i -X GET http://localhost:8080/people
HTTP/1.1 200 
Content-Type: application/hal+json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 12 Oct 2016 13:53:10 GMT

{
  "_embedded" : {
    "people" : [ {
      "name" : "John",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/people/1"
        },
        "people" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/people/1"
        },
        "parent" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/people/1/parent"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/people"
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/profile/people"
    },
    "search" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/people/search"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you thing it is wrong? If you connect to the _http://localhost:8080/people/1/parent_ link, what do you get?

Comment: @Cèsar It redirects me back to the link. Since I did not pass any value to parent, it should be null.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing either `@JoinColumn(name="parent_id")` or     `@OneToOne(mappedBy="id", cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)`

From reading your code i think you want `@JoinColumn`.

See [Hibernate self-referencing one-to-one relationship - mapped/owned side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28558591/hibernate-self-referencing-one-to-one-relationship-mapped-owned-side)